# how to unbind onbeforeunload event on javascript function call and page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

Please help me how to unbind onbeforeunload event on javascript function call .
Also I want to unbind onbeforeunload on page refresh.
 Actually I want to give pop up alert on page exit .For this I have successfully unbinded onbeforeunload from form submit button and anchor tags. Kindly help me. The code I have used is

```js
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(window).bind("onbeforeunload", function() {
      return confirm("Do you really want to close?")
    }
  );

  jQuery('a').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload')
  });

  jQuery("form").submit(function() {
    jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload')
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: change event name with beforeunload to onbeforeunload, it will be work

Comment: Thanks.... I have changed but please read the question carefully and help me.

Comment: i have posted my answer, is your problem resolved ?

Comment: No Sir. Thanks for your help . I am still stuck over page refresh and unbinding onbeforeunload event on javascript call.

Comment: I have updated my answer,

Answer (score 0):

Do some minor change in your code, it will be work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {        
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return confirm("Do you really want to close?")
    };

    jQuery('a').on('click', function () {
        jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload')
    });

    jQuery("form").submit(function () {
        jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload')
    });
});
```

Check this on jqfiddler, Message pop-up showing on refresh [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpkffm30/4/)